# code is running , but I get nothing, scanf problem

Tags: c, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
    int age;
    printf("Please, Enter your age: \n");
    scanf("%d", &age);
    printf("your were born in %d, did I get it right?", age);
    return 0;
}
```

the code does run but it gives nothing, not even the first printf is showing up, i'm working with vs code, please any possible solution!

Comment: It's a problem with your ide. Most likely the terminal settings.

Answer (score 1):

So, firstly syntactically your code is fine, the reason it is not running is a compiler error, not an error from your side.
Secondly, if I understand what you are trying to do correctly you should replace the age in the last printf with 2022-age to get the year so birth.

Comment: I doubt that it is a [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) error. A misconfigured [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) is more likely.

Comment: Yes, it can be that too, my point being there is no user error the syntax is correct.

Comment: Note that you can [edit] your answer to clarify it.